# Espresso set cursor for edittext

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to test an `EditText` that already contains some text using `Espresso`. The problem is that when I use `typeText()`, the cursor is placed at an arbitrary position within the text. I tried performing `click()` before using `typeTextIntoFocusedView` but the cursor is sometimes placed at the beginning of the `EditText`. I want to know is it possible to set the cursor at the end of the `EditText` before typing text into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found to do this is to get a reference to the `EditText` itself and use `EditText#setSelection()`. For example, to move the cursor to the end of the current text:

```
    val activity = activityRule.activity
    val tv = activity.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext)
    activity.runOnUiThread { tv.setSelection(tv.text.length) }
```

Comment: `.runOnUiThread{}` sucks. (So does Espresso - try to run test cases using `@UiThreadTest` wherever possible.) But if you must run your test case in a thread different from your UI, use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync{}` so you block until the UI event finishes and your case is safe to resume.

Answer (score 3):

A better way would be to use Espresso the way it's meant to be used: with actions on view matchers.

Example in Kotlin:

```kotlin
class SetEditTextSelectionAction(private val selection: Int) : ViewAction {

    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
        return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(EditText::class.java))
    }

    override fun getDescription(): String {
        return "set selection to $selection"
    }

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
        (view as EditText).setSelection(selection)
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```kotlin
onView(withId(R.id.my_text_view).perform(SetEditTextSelectionAction(selection))
```

An extra advantage over manually doing `findViewById()` is that you can combine this with matchers like `withSubString("my text")` if you don't have the ID of the view.

By the way: to change this into setting selection at the end of text you can simply remove the `selection: Int` constructor argument and change `setSelection(selection)` to `setSelection(view.text.lastIndex)`.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, since it follows Espresso guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success by inserting the `KeyCode`s for "Home" and "End". These work just like on your desktop keyboard, by moving the cursor to either the beginning or end of the `EditText`. For example:

```
onView(withId(R.id.myView))
    .perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MOVE_HOME))
```

To move to the end, you can use `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MOVE_END`, and you can move left or right using `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT` and `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post my answer since I just had this problem and none of the other answers solved my problem.

I used a GeneralClickAction to click on the right side of the edit text which put the cursor at the end of the EditText where I wanted it. After that I used the TypeTextAction and disabled the tapToFocus behavior by passing in false to the constructor:

```java
onView(withId(R.id.edit_text))
.perform(
  new GeneralClickAction(Tap.SINGLE, GeneralLocation.CENTER_RIGHT, Press.FINGER, 0, 0, null),
  new TypeTextAction(text, false)
);
```